# Use array of String Resource IDs with ListAdapter?

Tags: java, android, listactivity

I have an array of class "EditableListItem" each containing a string resource id. I want to create a list with the values of all these strings. The problem is that the items on my list end up showing the resource ID instead of the actual string.

Class EditableListItem:

```
public class EditableListItem {
    private int title_id;

    public EditableListItem(int title_id) {
        this.title_id = title_id;
    }
    //...
}
```

My List Activity:

```
    // Instantiate the list of samples.
    EditableListItem[] allItems = new EditableListItem[]{
            new EditableListItem(R.string.dialer),
            new EditableListItem(R.string.clock)
    };

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<EditableListItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, allItems));
```

How can I make my List show the String values instead of their IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` will use `.toString()` method to show the text.

Override it and use `getString(title_id)` to get the string (You will need the context).

You could:

- Create a private field `String stringRapp`
- Edit constructor to take a Context
- Use this context and do `stringRapp = context.getString(title_id);`

If you are are sure resource ID never changes and will reference to the same string always.

If not:

- Take Context from constructor
- Save it in a field `Context context`
- In `.toString()` method, `return context.getString(title_id)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`getResources().getString(R.string.yourstring)`

to **get the String value of a String-resource**.